# Display Ok/Cancel popup for each iteration within server-side loop?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-4.0

Is it possible to display a popup for every iteration within a `for`, `foreach` or any other server-side loop?

For example, something like this:

```
foreach (GridDataItem item in RadGridEmps.MasterTableView.Items)
{
    CheckBox ChkChange = item.FindControl("ChkChange") as CheckBox;
    if (ChkChange.Checked)
    {
        oldEmpId = item.GetDataKeyValue("oldEmpId").ToString();
        newEmpId = item.GetDataKeyValue("newEmpId").ToString();

        var msg = string.Format("Change from {0} to {1}?", oldEmpId, newEmpId);
        OkCancel_Popup(msg);

        if (OK)
            UpdateEmp(oldEmpId, newEmpId);
        else if (Cancel)
            //Do Nothing and go to following row
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just use `MessageBox.Show` like below

```
if (DialogResult.OK == MessageBox.Show(msg))
    UpdateEmp(oldEmpId, newEmpId);
else
    //Do Nothing
```

Comment: No, you can't use messageboxes in asp.net. It's for Windows Forms.